# Android intent resolution

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm building a application to search for torrents. So when the user select one, I want to open the client that the user has installed (typical intent-based activity).

On my test machine, I have transdroid installed. Transdroid declares its intent this way:
http://code.google.com/p/transdroid/source/browse/android/AndroidManifest.xml

I launch the activity this way:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url));
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

While I believe this should work, the browser get launched instead. The URL is a direct URL, ends with "torrent" so it should match Transdroid's filters.

I also tried setDataAndType with `type="application/x-bittorrent"` but I get an exception "no activity found to handle the intent".

I know that Transdroid is correctly installed because after the torrent file gets downloaded by the browser, I can click on it and open Transdroid.

Comment: Several of the answers here could be considered correct. One issue you probably ran into was [this](http://code.google.com/p/transdroid/issues/detail?id=453&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Reporter%20Stars). Transdroid itself has not defined its intent-filter correctly, hence all torrent links have failed to open it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some pieces of code ant this one works for me (i.e. it lauches transdroid):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent"));
i.setType("application/x-bittorrent");
```

I do not know but the behavior is very strange. For instance, if I change only two lines, then it launches browser:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setType("application/x-bittorrent");
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed it launches transdroid but there are 2 problems: (1) it doesn't add the torrent to the list, and (2) if I remove Transdroid it throws a "no activity found" exception. What I really want is let the user choose between applications, and if he has no torrent client fall back to the browser (maybe I'll have to do this fallback manually, though).

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://site.com/tor.torrent")));
```

Note that the file that you link to needs to either have the .torrent extension or be of mime type application/x-bittorrent. Otherwise the intent mechanism of Android cannot match it with one of Transdroid's Intents and will instead launch the browser. If you then download the file using the browser and 'open' it, it will open with Transdroid.

If this doesn't work, procide us with an example URL of a torrent that doesn't work.

If you want to catch the case that Transdorid isn't installed yet, you can do something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://site.com/tor.torrent");
if (context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)  > 0) {
    startActivity(i);
} else {
    // Alert that Transdroid is not available and link to the installer
}
```

Or use an Intent chooser:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://site.com/tor.torrent");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.some_dialog_title)));
```

Answer (score 0):

From android [resurces](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/can-i-use-this-intent.html) you can find a method to check if an intent exist.

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Here an example how to use it using Barcode Scanner intent.

```
@Override 
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    final boolean scanAvailable = isIntentAvailable(this,
            "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

    MenuItem item; item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_add);
    item.setEnabled(scanAvailable);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 
}
```